# Unreferenced Array not so Unreferenced after "slice"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

**Note:** this isn't one of the millions dups of the common array copy 'problem' where using `arr.slice(0)` fixes this 'problem'

That said, I want to understand why I am getting this unexpected result:

```
var oldArr = [[1,2],[3,4]];
var find = oldArr[1];

var newArr = oldArr.slice(0);
console.log(newArr.indexOf(find)); //1?

//proof that newArr is NOT referenced to oldArr
newArr[0] = "Hi";
newArr[1] = "How are you?";
console.log(oldArr+" "+newArr); //"1,2,3,4 Hi,How are you?"
```

[jsFildde Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yLQ3u/)

If you replace `find` with any of the following alternatives, it returns the expected `-1`:

- Use `[3,4]` directly
- Use a variable holding `[3,4]`
- Use a variable with reference of another array holding `[3,4]`

I can't find any explanation on why there is any difference between these last three methods and the first example. As far as I know, there shouldn't be any.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

There are **three array objects** created.

Only the outer one is being `slice`'d. This results in a "shallow copy".

Consider this:

```
var a = [1,2]
var b = [3,4]
var c = [a,b]
var d = c.slice(0)
d[0] === a       // true, which means it is the /same/ object
d[0][0] = "Hi!"
a                // ["Hi!", 2]
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working as expected

`indexOf` searches by reference and not value, therefore if two objects do not `===` each other, `indexOf` will not find them

In your case:

```
var oldArr = [[1,2],[3,4]];
var find = oldArr[1];

var newArr = oldArr.slice(0);
```

`find` points to the array [3,4];
so newArray contains 2 objects (the two arrays).
If you want to see what is really going on try doing find.push(5)

Comment: +1 for the bit about `indexOf`. I would use the term "identity" and say it is an "identity search" (vs. an "equality search"), except for the non-object primitives where "identity" and "equality" are the same thing ;-)