# Why does my array.slice(0) not create a clone?

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

I'm creating a base array, which I'm appending information to. This makes my base array:

```
 make_shell = function (opts) {
   var x, shell, shell_row;

   shell = [];
   for (x = 0; x < opts.points; x += 1) {
      shell_row = [];
      shell_row.push(opts.delta * x);
      shell.push(shell_row);
   }
   return shell;
 };

raw_graph = make_shell({
   "points": data_points_per_channel,
   "delta": x_delta
});
```

Then I want to run several methods and each one needs a clean copy of `raw_graph`. However if I do this:

```
make_graph_struct = function (opts) {
  var j, k, len, struct, row, runner, series;

  console.log("RAW")
  console.log(opts.shell);

  return struct;
};


// Graph #1 - works
var test_a = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graph-a"),
  make_graph_struct({
     "shell": raw_graph.slice(0),
     "display": [[0,0]],
     "total_channels": total_channels,
     "points": data_points_per_channel,
     "data": tmp_data
   }),
   {...}
 );

// Graph #2 - ERROR raw_graph now includes values added in first call
var test_b = new Dygraph(
   document.getElementById("graph-b"),
   make_graph_struct({
    "shell": raw_graph.slice(0),
    "display": [[1,4000]],
    "total_channels": total_channels,
    "points": data_points_per_channel,
    "data": tmp_data
   }), {...}
);
```

Problem is, `raw_graph` only is in it's raw form on the first call. After that, every call adds the value I need in the respective call, so *Graph2*, `raw_graph` will include

```
[setter, value_from_call_1]
```

**Question**:
How do I use `slice` correctly or why are my per graph values ending up in my `raw_graph` when **slice** should only make a clone?

**EDIT**: here is a jsbin. Check the console.log [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1422/edit)

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: give me a minute, copy pasting

Comment: I undertand your problem,not your code.But you know that slice will only "clone" the array,not the values inside the array right?

Comment: Mh. But that would mean I need to re-generate my base array every time I need it?

Comment: see [here](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1422/edit). I want to have a "clean" `x` every time I need it.

Comment: @ajax333221: not sure. I'm looking for a way to make a "clone" from a base array. So if I need to call 20 methods and all are based on the my base array, then the base array should not change

Comment: if [I remember, slice(0) only copies one level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891706/absolutely-reference-free-array-copy-with-nested-arrays) and don't work well in nested things, I moved to create copies with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))`